# Form validation empty field when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to add validation before form submit. There's an alternative input field, let's call this "Optional" and there's checkboxes "Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", "Checkbox3". When user choose one from this checkboxes, then he must fill input "Optional", if it is empty then he can't submit form and get's some pop-up alert with info to fill this.

I have something like this:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["form"]["nrumowy"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Numer umowy musi zostać uzupełniony.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

But this input field "nrumowy" must be filled in all situations, so everything okay, and now I want add something similiar but only when one of "Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", "Checkbox3" are checked.

Comment: please show the html code to sort out problem.

Comment: Then why don't you add conditions for what you want?

Comment: @Imran I'm newbie at JS, i don't know how to add conditions to make this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply get the values of these checkboxes before that, and if one of them is not checked, exit the function.

```
function validateForm() {
    var frm = document.forms["form"];
    if (!frm["Checkbox1"].checked && !frm["Checkbox2"].checked && !frm["Checkbox3"].checked) return;

    var x = frm["nrumowy"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Numer umowy musi zostać uzupełniony.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! But alert works only when this three checkboxes is checked operator "||" means "or", so I don't know how to make alert works also when one of this checkbox is checked?

Comment: Than it's &&. Or see Sameer Sawant's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Following code will work instantly while filling the form.

**jquery code**

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["form"]["nrumowy"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Numer umowy musi zostać uzupełniony.");
        return false;
    }
    var op = document.forms["form"]["optional"].value;
    if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0 && op==""){
        alert("you must fill Optional field");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's disable that input field, I don't want disable this input, I want to add alert when someone checked a specified checkbox, and when he click submit form then he got alert "you must fill Optional field".

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your requirement. You can tailor it further to suite your HTML.

Comment: Please approve this if it helped you @user3180931

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add something similiar but only when one of "Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", "Checkbox3" are checked. Then see if following code helps you.

```js
function validateForm() {
  
  if(document.getElementById("Checkbox1").checked  ||
     document.getElementById("Checkbox2").checked  ||
     document.getElementById("Checkbox3").checked  ||
     {
    
    var x = document.forms["form"]["nrumowy"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Numer umowy musi zostać uzupełniony.");
        return false;
    }
     
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for your answers, I got now this:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var frm = document.forms["form"];
    if (!frm["check_list1"].checked && !frm["check_list2"].checked && !frm["check_list3"].checked) return;

    var x = frm["tematyka"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Tematyka artykułu musi zostać uzupełniona.");
        return false;
    }


}
</script>
<script>
function validateForm2() {
var x2 = document.forms["form"]["nrumowy"].value;
    if (x2 == null || x2 == "") {
        alert("Numer umowy musi zostać uzupełniony.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="preview.php" onsubmit="return (validateForm() & validateForm2());">
```

And alerts works, but after user click OK then he goes to preview.php page. When there's only one onsubmit function then this works great, but when I try to combine this two functions then there is a some error.